# Audio playback device already in use

Tags: windows-7, audio, headset, playback

I have a headset: Creative SB Recon3D. Since today (after power went out) sound doesn't work through my headset on the PC, it works fine on a Playstation 3.

I have Windows 7 64x. When I go to "playback devices" and want to "test" my headset, it gives me the following error:

"The device is being used by another application. Please close any devices that are playing audio to this device and try again."

What can I do? I have already tried re-installed drivers for my headset etc.

Comment: As usual, have you tried rebooting your computer? Do other headphones or speakers work on the computer?

Comment: Yes, other speakers and headphones work absolutely fine. Tried restarting many times. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with a computer in a business environment. I tried every driver add/change/remove/update in the book. I eventually re-imaged (reloaded the operating system) to resolve the issue.